# Where does gethostbyaddr() get hostname from on Debian?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I am troubleshooting an issue where `socket.gethostbyaddr(name)` sometimes returns non-UTF-8 characters in the hostname and alias fields, and that is causing the code to fail with a UTF-8 decode error.

Where is that returned result coming from?

I am on Alpine 3.12.3 on a Raspberry Pi running Home Assistant.

Running the following Python code:

```
print(socket.gethostbyaddr('homeassistant.local.hass.io'))
```

Should return:

```
('core-matter-server.y', ['core-matter-server.y'], ['xxx.xx.32.1'])
```

but sometimes returns:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb7 in position 20: invalid start byte
```

or

```
('core-matter-server.PwΥ\x7f', ['core-matter-server.PwΥ\x7f'], ['xxx.xx.32.1'])
```

The characters shown in the last, corrupted response vary. What's also weird is if I restart Python, the result is valid, once.

So my fundamental question is: Since it's clear from the runtime error and the second aberrant result that the result is getting corrupted somehow, where should I look to determine the source of the corruption? 
I'm running Python 3.11.5.

Comment: Since `gethostbyaddr` takes an IP address, what if you use `gethostbyname` on the name, and then throw that result into `gethostbyaddr`? E.g., `socket.gethostbyaddr(socket.gethostbyname('homeassistant.local.hass.io'))`.

Comment: `gethostbyaddr` calls the libc `gethostbyaddr` function [under the hood](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8d92b6eff3bac45e7d4871c46c4511218b9b685a/Modules/socketmodule.c#L6034).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. ```socket.gethostbyaddr(socket.gethostbyname('homeassistant.local.hass.io'))'``` gives the same UTF-8 error.

Comment: It could be something in the locale of your system; you can have a first check with just the command `locale` to see what it's all set to.

Comment: That command doesn't seem to work on Alpine 3.12.3, I tried both locale and sudo locale.

Comment: It looks like Home Assistant is reporting the hostname based on all  of its add-on components that are using a websocket. I uninstalled the add-on that I think was the offender and now the host name is that of a different add-on but no longer returning invalid UTF-8 characters. Thanks for the help!